# Logger is reading configuration but shows only error logs

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I get Logger on **A.class** constructor:

```
public class A {

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(A.class);

    public void methodA() {
        logger.info("log info");
        logger.error("log error");
    }
}
```

The configuration file: **Log4j2.xml** is within classpath:

```
<Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

There is no error that log4j properties are not found.
But it shows only error logs.
I tried running the project with Eclipse and IntelliJ but the results are the same. Java is 11.

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @JWoodchuck no, not yet

Comment: I think your xml is incomplete. See my additional answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to the order of precedence of log4j configuration property files. Basically, log4j scans the classpath for specific *properties*, *yaml*, *json* and *xml* files and stops when it finds a match.

For details, see the second section [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html), titled **Automatic Configuration**. Notice in that list *log4j2.xml* is listed at number 9. My understanding is that if log4j finds any of the other specific files first, it will go with them instead. So maybe check you don't have any of those other files.

This would be consistent with there being no error indicating log4j properties are not found.

To [debug](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html), though, you can add the *log4j2.debug* system property before your logger statements:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.setProperty("log4j2.debug", "");
logger.info("log info");
logger.error("log error");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing a missing appender ("Console") and also missing the [Configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#XML) tag.

Try expanding your **log4j2.xml** to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: It doesn't matter I tried with different configurations file with Appenders too.

Comment: Does adding system property log4j2.debug give any useful feedback?

Comment: debug level doesn't change nothing

Comment: Hm, adding the log4j2.debug property (see above) should print internal Log4j2 logging to the console to give you more specific feedback on what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by:

- updating dependencies to the latest versions:

  ```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
  ```
- adding config to the classpath (src/main/resources) in case if it's not added there must be "log4j.configurationFile" system property set. [doc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)

In the latest versions log4j2 doesn't inform about config file not found and loads DefaultConfiguration with log level `error`.